# why post request sent before calling axios.all( ) method

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, axios, httprequest

i want to send 10 post request by using axios.all() method here is my code

```
const array = []

for(let x=0 ;x<10;x++){
    array.push(axios.post(url,{data : x}))
 }

axios.all(array)
```

but it not working as it should, when for loop starts the post request sent one by one in
the for loop even when i comment out axios.all(array) still for loop send post requests. i dont understand why post request sent when axios.post is push into an array

i try also try this code

```
const rOne = axios.post(url,{data : "1"})
const rTwo = axios.post(url,{data : "2"})
const rThree = axios.post(url,{data : "3"})
const rFour = axios.post(url,{data : "4"})
const rfive = axios.post(url,{data : "5"})
const rSix = axios.post(url,{data : "6"})
const rSeven = axios.post(url,{data : "7"})
const rEight = axios.post(url,{data : "8"})
const rNine = axios.post(url,{data : "9"})
const rTen = axios.post(url,{data : "10"})

const array = [rOne,rTwo,rThree,rFour,rfive,rSix,rSeven,rEight,rNine,rTen]

axios.all(array)
```

again as soon as const declared post request is sent before axios.all(array) again when i comment out axios.all(array) still post request sent

i try to search on internet but cant find solution please help me out

Comment: because you call the the axios.post() method before you push it

Comment: It's because you send the request when `axios.post()` is called. Whether you handle the promise it returns through `axios.all()` makes no difference to that, the requests are still sent.

Comment: Why would you expect a call to `axios.post()` to *not* start an HTTP request?

Comment: i followed this article https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/axios/all and try to same as he does.

Comment: in my second code which i motioned in question, i create instance of http requests and never called them before axios.all( )  then why request sent when instance created. sorry if im sound stupid but i cant understand its fundamental reason please help me out